# How do you show a sequence of numbers is not random?

Tags: statistical-significance, randomness, sequential-pattern-mining

Let's say I take the following sequence of numbers:

[image: not a random sequence]

Obviously it's not random - each value is close to either .5, 1 or 2.

What test would you use to show that it's not random?

Comment: Interesting question! It depends on what you consider 'random'. Would you like to test whether these numbers come from a normal distribution? Or test whether these numbers come from a uniform distribution? What type of randomness would you like to compare it to?  Does the order matter?

Comment: Thanks! the order doesn't matter. I'm interested in showing that if the values could be anything at all (any value between 0 and whatever), then they shouldn't all cluster around 0.5, 1, and 2. If one were to plot them, for example, then a random sequence should be a curve, but this would come out as a series of spikes... so yes I suppose showing they are non-normal is a good start...

Comment: That's not what random means. I could generate that exact sequence *randomly*, say with a mixture of normals with means at 0.5, 1, and 2, and small variances. You're going to have to be more precise about what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: ok I see what you mean. Specifically I'm interested in showing patterns in music are not random. Specifically, rhythmic patterns in Western music tend to follow the pattern whereby each note is the same length as the previous one, or else half the length, or twice the length, etc. If note lengths were generated randomly (with any value at all possible) then you shouldn't get a repeated pattern like this. That's what I'm trying to show (the notes in the sequence are the relative lengths of the notes in a Mozart Horn concerto). : )

Comment: Usually tests for randomness are done using a chi square test.

Comment: Why would you test a hypothesis that's clearly false; you describe the situation that plainly exists - that lengths tend to stay constant, halve or double. So if it's well known that Western music is not selecting consecutive length ratios randomly, why test it? What would be the point?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/221/

Answer (score 3):

> Specifically I'm interested in showing patterns in music are not
> random. Specifically, rhythmic patterns in Western music tend to
> follow the pattern whereby each note is the same length as the
> previous one, or else half the length, or twice the length, etc. If
> note lengths were generated randomly (with any value at all possible)
> then you shouldn't get a repeated pattern like this

Almost always, when you're trying to construct a test, you want to think about not only the null hypothesis that you're trying to disprove but also the alternatives that you want to be sensitive to.

In this case, the null may be that there is some distribution $F$, perhaps specific to a movement or section of a movement, where the note lengths are independent draws from $F$. Your alternative may be that the length of a note depends on the length of the previous note.

One way to handle this is to build a transition model for the length of the next note in terms of the length of the current note (and possibly the past two notes, etc) and estimate the dependence.

Or the hypotheses might be different: if it turns out that all notes are a power of two times the length of some minimal note (but that order isn't important) would that count as "random"? If so, you want to test whether the individual ratios are "close enough" to powers of two, where "close enough" would have to be defined in terms of how equal a performer could realistically make the notes.

The more precisely you can characterise what counts a 'random' and 'not random', the better you will be able to distinguish the two statistically

Comment: Thanks Thomas! The null hypothesis here is that each note length has no bearing on what came before it. The values in the list are the length of each note relative to the one that came before. So, the first value is the length of the second note in the tune relative to the one before (close to the same length), etc.

Alternatively, the notes could stand in a relation to their prior notes like 0.3, 1.2, 0.8, 16, .00001, 5002, 0.4, etc . But instead they all stand in a whole-number proportion of the previous one. I want to show that this is unlikely to happen by chance.

Comment: The 'random relation' to the prior notes you just mentioned seems to be unbounded (any value between 0 and +infinity will do). This makes it hard to test. For the null hypothesis, you'd need to specify a distribution of such relations (e.g. the uniform distribution between 0 and 4).

Comment: Once you have hypothesized a distribution, you can show that your sequence is _unlikely_ to be random draws from that distribution.

Comment: Thanks good point, what if I supposed that if the values were random, they could be anything between the longest relative length in the sequence above (2.03) and the shortest (.3). So if the relative length 'could be' for each note, any value between 0.3 and 2.03, but in fact they all cluster around 0.5, 1, and 2 - would that do it? I'm interested in showing for example that if I take some string of random sounds (like the sounds produced by a cat walking haphazardly over a piano keyboard), then I shouldn't get the kind of regular relative lengths that we have in the above pattern.

Comment: The walking cat won't produce random sounds, either.  The big problem lurking here is the lack of any usable characterization of "random."  The concept encompasses both the relative frequencies of observations as well as their sequence.  A second big problem is that demonstrating a sequence of sounds is not random (in any sense) will be next to useless in this context.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I came up with the following method:

You identify the 'target values' you think each number is closest to - in this case, 0.5, 1, 1.5, and 2.

Then you cluster the values in the series into groups, according to which target value they are closest to (so for each number, ask whether it's closest to  0.5, 1, 1.5, or 2).

Next, you ask, for the target-value it's closest to, how close is it to that value. You get a measure for this by subtracting the value from the target value it's closest to.

If all the numbers are indeed very close to one of those target values, you will have a series of values close to zero.

Then you generate a random series of values in the same range (e.g. 0.3-2.03), and apply the same procedure to that random series of values.

You will end up with two sets of values. You apply an unpaired t-test to the two sets of values. If the original set is indeed clustered around the three target values, then there should be a statistically significant difference between the two sets.

Comment: I would suggest some tweaks. Change your "procedure" to result in a single number aka "test statistic". After you find the distance between each number and its closest "target value," take the sum of these differences in absolute value, or perhaps the sum of these differences squared. You expect this sum to be close to 0 for your real-world data, but far from 0 for uniformly random data in the same range, right? Then...

Comment: ...generate not *one* but *many* (say, 1000) random datasets. Each should have the same sample size as your real dataset. Compute your test statistic for each of the random datasets. Finally, find the proportion of these random datasets whose test-statistic is smaller than your real-data's test statistic; that proportion is a simulated p-value.

Comment: Put another way: If you generate just *one* random dataset and compare it to your real data with a t-test, that's not convincing enough. You ought to be comparing your real dataset to the whole *distribution* of outcomes that could have happened if your implied null hypothesis (that the data should behave like uniform random values in the range 0.3-2.03) was true.

Comment: OK, one last thought on how to frame this. The approach in your post is equivalent to making a plot of your data, and making a plot of a *single* random dataset, and saying they don't look similar. Almost certainly true in your case -- but much more convincing would be to compare a plot of your data vs *100* plots of random datasets, and show that your real plot stands out as looking very different from all 100 of the truly-random plots. See Di Cook's work on visual inference and the "lineup protocol": https://dicook.github.io/nullabor/articles/nullabor.html

Comment: Because this procedure is very specifically adapted to the data you have observed, it would be impossible to develop it rigorously.  In particular, the p-values of the proposed t-tests would be meaningless.  You would be better off *displaying* and *describing* your data rather than pretending that some *ad hoc* test shows they are "not random," which isn't saying anything worthwhile (or well defined) in the first place.  @Civilstat's suggestion to develop a lineup protocol is an excellent one.

Comment: @civilstat these are really interesting ideas, thank you. The sum of differences squared will basically make the differences (if any) more pronounced and easier to detect, right? We get a single value for each sample, generating a set of values for the set of samples; and then we test these values against 1000 sets of randomly generated sequences. For alpha = 0.5, we should expect the sequence to be significantly different from 950 of the randomly generated data sets. Right?

Comment: @cathalcom Squaring the differences is just one way to make them all positive, so that it's meaningful to sum them. It sounds like we might be talking past each other; let me try to rephrase my suggestions. Above, you posted a sequence of n=20 numbers, and you want to know if *this* sequence "looks different" from what we'd usually see in random sequences of 20 numbers in this range. One way to do that is to draw a dotplot or histogram of your real 20 numbers, and compare it to many (100?) dotplots of 20 random numbers each, and see if the real plot looks like an outlier...

Comment: Another way, if you don't want to look at 100 plots, is to compute a single (relevant) numeric summary on your n=20 cases -- then see if that summary is an outlier compared to what you see when compute the same summary on 1000 random samples of size n=20. Compare your real data's sum-of-squared-diffs ONCE to this set of 1000 sums-of-squared-diffs from the 1000 random samples. If your real sum-of-sqd-diffs is among the smallest 5%, it's "significant at level alpha=0.05" by this informal test. However, to be clear, ...

Comment: ...I would NOT run a t-test of your real sample against one random sample; then another t-test of your real sample against a 2nd random sample; and so on. None of those t-tests is meaningful individually, and doing it 1000 times would not be meaningful either. I hope that helps to clarify the difference between what I suggested vs what it seems you had in mind.